# Infinite loop error when using header in observer

Tags: magento

I'm just trying to set up terms and conditions page after a successful login. All seems to to working well. I am getting the post data through the form which I have placed in CMS Page with identifier 'general-conditions'. The problem is only in the

`header('Location: '.Mage::getUrl('general-conditions'));`

If I comment out this line.. page loads properly but if I don't it gets caught in infinite loop.

Could anyone please help me, that's the only thing left and I've spent a lot of time on it.
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php



Class Rik_Terms_Model_Observer{
public function checkGeneralTerms(){

  if (Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {

  $id       =   Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getId();
  $customer =   Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
  $customerData = $customer->getData();

  $groupId = Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
  $groupName = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId)->getCode();
  $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

  if($customer->getGeneralTerms()=='0'){
      $pageIdentifier = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->checkIdentifier("general-conditions", $storeId);
      if ($pageIdentifier){      
            header('Location: '.Mage::getUrl('general-conditions')); // problem
            die();

        }

    }
 }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found later, it was actually conflicting with extended version of my CMS Module.